# How do I update Opportunity Product with Product's Custom Fields Value

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

I have custom fields in Products. I want to populate these information in Opportunity Products. Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: A simple workflow with field update will work. You have to pass by OpportunityLineItem.PriceBookEntry.Product2.MyField__c

Comment: I would suggest @brovasi move his comment to a post, then you can mark his post as the answer and close this question down.

Answer (score 2):

A simple workflow with field update will work. You have to pass by OpportunityLineItem.PriceBookEntry.Product2.MyField__c

Answer (score 1):

Use please formula field. this way you can propagate field from product without any update

Comment: Workflow rule may be better in certain situations. Especially around pricing. If the product were to change, you wouldn't want closed Opportunities to also change.

Answer (score 0):

You can take trigger approach or you can go workflow rule field update approach.