# Populating Opportunity custom field with multiple unique ProductOpp values / related Products

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

Similar to this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162582/populating-opportunity-custom-field-with-multiple-productopp-field-values), my goal is to populate a custom Opportunity field called "Data Source Names" that contains the related product names and list price.  I want the field to populate with ALL related products.

So far, I created a formula field on OppProduct that pulls in the Product Name + List Price for each OppProduct:
*Opportunity Line Item Formula = PricebookEntry.Product2.Name & " " & "-" & " USD " & TEXT(ListPrice)*.

I then created a process builder on OppProduct for anytime a new product is added to an opportunity, update the Opportunity.Data Source Name with Opportunity Line Item Formula that has the Product Name + List Price.
[image]
[image]
[image]

My issue with the PB is that it only pulls the most recently added product to the custom field. Is there a way to aggregate all related products to the field from OppProducts to the Opportunity object using process builder?  If not, how do I use apex trigger to do so?

PS: Linebreaks BR() does now work for formula fields in process builders. This is a known issue so formatting for the field population can be ignored.

Comment: You can do this with the concatenate rollup feature in the free [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/wiki/Getting-Started-With-DLRS) package.  Also see this Chatter group for support:  https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009O5pCAE

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded the DLRS to a sandbox and testing right now!  I also opted for using a flow to accomplish this and learned that it may not be the most dynamic solution given that if a product was to be deleted on the related list, the flow doesn't know how to update that.